# XPath: How to translate multiple Strings?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to translate some Strings in XPath but I'm getting some weird outputs.

That's the function:

```
translate(translate(translate(translate('1 day 23 hours 30 minutes 25 seconds','day','dag'),'hours','uur'),'minutes','minuut'),'seconds','seconden')
```

And the currently output is:

```
1 dag 23 uur 30 minrut 25 tcund
```

But what I need is:  `1 dag 23 uur 30 minuut 25 seconden`

Is there any special way of translating multiple substrings at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `translate()` works. When you translate:

```
translate('minutes seconds','hours','uur')
```

the expected result is:

```
minrte ecund
```

because you are actually telling the processor to replace the occurrences of the first three **letters** in the second argument:

```
'h', 'o', 'u'
```

as they occur in the string 'minutes seconds' with the corresponding characters

```
'u', 'u', 'r'
```

respectively, and **remove** the characters `'r'` and `'s'`, since they have no corresponding replacements in the third argument.

If you want to replace full **words**, and are using XPath 2.0, then you can use the `replace()` function.

```
replace(replace(replace(replace('1 day 23 hours 30 minutes 25 seconds','day','dag'),'hours','uur'),'minutes','minuut'),'seconds','seconden')
```