# Python/Selenium search for replaced element

Tags: python, selenium

This is my simple selenium search functionality:

`browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(),"{}")]'.format("XXXXXX"))`

Imagine that label will contain `XXXYXXX` text, but I would like to find it by using `XXXXXX`

Do we have in Selenium feature which will replace MULTIPLE times:

- Like this: `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(text().replace("Y",""),"{}")]'.format("XXXXXX"))`

Have tried...with no luck:

- `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(replace(text(),"Y",""),"{}")]'.format("XXXXXX"))`

Comment: I know selenium(xpath) does have something like translate() but I'm not 100% sure how to use it correctly

Comment: Or is it as simple as `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(translate(text(),"Y",""),"{}")]'.format("XXXXXX"))`

Comment: Can `translate()` function do part/multiple replacement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301459/xpath-how-to-translate-multiple-strings

Comment: What is the reason `Imagine that label will contain XXXYXXX text, but I would like to find it by using XXXXXX` you wanna do this ? you won't right, since element won't be present with `XXXXXX` they are present with `XXXYXXX`

Comment: @cruisepandey I have tried to simplify the question, to find the actual functionality to do so...I have the list of options which I have to find on the website, but they are a bit different, so in reality, all that I want is to remove all the brackets and double spaces. I have constructed the question ... that way so I will learn how to do it in the future....